# Openldap support for sha256 and sha512 password format

Tags: ldap, openldap

How to configure Openldap server for {SHA256} and {SHA512} password format ? is this functionality available in latest Openldap or still we have to add external module( slapd-sha2.so)?

Comment: Off topic, but if you've identified the shared library it comes in, it's difficult to understand why you're asking,

Comment: I previously used this shared library which is not a part of official openldap release.since most of the server nowadays supports sha2 password format, i want to know ,is openldap officialy supports sha2 passwords.

Answer (score 0):

There is no will to include SHA2 support in base OpenLDAP installation.

"At present there is no need to change anything in the core since SHA-2 support can be dynamically loaded. Don't fix what isn't broken."

Howard Chu
CTO, Symas Corp.
Director, Highland Sun
Chief Architect, OpenLDAP

Ref:http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-bugs/201205/msg00055.html